# rails deploy to server error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, server

I just execute `cap production deploy` on my local,

But it shows these error messages.

[image]

Can someone give me some advises to fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have `java` installed and in your `PATH`?